# How to implement "instanceOf" in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

or say get class name or get type name

so that can work on major popular web container/servers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`${foo.class.name}` returns the fully qualidied name of `foo`.

But `instanceof` being already something you should rarely use in a well-design OO program, it should be used even less in the JSP EL, where methods are called dynamically without caring of the actual type, and where the end goal should only be to generate markup.

Comment: Thank you. But `${foo.class.name}` seems not working under Tomcat7 until additional config change which unfortunately I don't have the authority to get into. The class name check takes place in a table tagx file who works for several places. However now for a specific table I need to check the object class name to output its field value. I don't know how to compromise that with a better idea.

Comment: In tomcat 7 (so with JSP EL 2.2) you can actually do `${foo.getClass().name}` and it works...

Comment: If you want to make it work in both Tomcat 6 and 7, you have two choices:
- Use ${foo['class'].name}, that works in both versions
- OR configure Tomcat 7 to accept the old format with -Dorg.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK=true

Comment: Downvote because if you don't use instanceof then your model and view have a hard dependency with each other.

Comment: @PhilipRego So if you have ${someModel.foo} you have a hard dependency between the model and the view, but it you somehow have <%= if (request.getAttribute("someModel") instanceof com.mycompany.myapp.SomeModel) %>, you don't? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Ya because if you use another model with ${someModel.foo} , then youll get "Method getFoo() not found". If I check first with instanceof I won't try to evaluate ${someModel.foo}.

Comment: That has absolutely nothing to do with "having a hard dependency". And if a view is **supposed** to be able to call ${someModel.foo} but can't, then you have a bug, and the bug simply needs to be fixed. Testing if someModel is an instance of SomeModel and... not doing anything useful if it is not just hides the bug behind a blank page.

Comment: I'm using the same JSP for success and error. I get one bean for success and another for error. In error case, I want ${someModel.foo} to show nothing but get no method exception. Only solutions I know is use instanceof or create another JSP.

Comment: That's what happens when you violate the single responsibility principle. Don't blame my answer for your bad design...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the class of object `foo`, you can use `${foo.getClass()}`*. This allows you to get its class names using one of [`Class`'s name getters](https://www.baeldung.com/java-class-name), such as [getSimpleName()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName()). For example, if `foo` is a `String`, `${foo.getClass().simpleName}` would print "String".

*: If you target at least a Servlet 3.0 container like Tomcat 7+, Glassfish 3+, JBoss AS 6+, etc with a `web.xml` conforming to at least Servlet 3.0.