# Expression Language Exception - Failed to parse simple expression

Tags: jsp, tomcat7

I'm not quite sure what is wrong with the expression

`${exception.class.simpleName eq 'AccessDeniedException'}`

but it's giving me a `javax.el.ELException`.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/exception/AccessDeniedException.jsp (line: 45, column: 28) "${exception.class.simpleName eq 'AccessDeniedException'}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${exception.class.simpleName eq 'AccessDeniedException'}]
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:408)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:199)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1223)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:875)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1539)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:894)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1539)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:475)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1795)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:217)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

I'm using Tomcat 7 as part of Spring's tc Server 2.7, hence using javax.el version 2.2.

Comment: I'm not as *smart* as JSP EL parser. Please post *relevant* code.

Comment: It _is_ posted - `${exception.class.simpleName eq 'AccessDeniedException'}` is the relevant code... There is an variable in scope named `exception` which is a subclass of 'java.lang.Exception'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348378/how-to-implement-instanceof-in-jstl/11348758#comment16435924_11348758) to a previous answer of mine:

In tomcat 7 (so with JSP EL 2.2) you can actually do `${foo.getClass().simpleName}` and it works...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks JB Nizet. I have been trying to fix this issue from 1 week.

${foo.class} worked fine on my colleague's system as he is using Tomcat6 where as I used to get "javax.el.ELException" because I'm using Tomcat7.

${foo.getClass()} fixed the issue on Tomcat7.