# What is the proper way to style the error message for Global Message?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I want to apply some script and styling for a specfic error message for the corresponding GlobalMessage class, and wanted to know the way to achieve this without disturbing other error messages or flash messages from this class.

Answer (score 1):

Extend class `de.hybris.platform.acceleratorstorefrontcommons.controllers.util.GlobalMessage` like this:

```
class StylableGlobalMessage extends GlobalMessage {
  private cssClass;
  setCssClass...
  getCssClass...
}
```

Create a new method to add this message to the model. Analogue to
`de.hybris.platform.acceleratorstorefrontcommons.controllers.util.GlobalMessages#addMessage`

```
final StylableGlobalMessage message = new StylableGlobalMessage();
message.setCode(messageKey);
message.setAttributes(attributes != null ? Arrays.asList(attributes) : Collections.emptyList());
message.setCssClass(cssClass);

List<GlobalMessage> currentMessages = (List<GlobalMessage>) model.getModelMap().get(messageHolder);
// Check if null etc.
currentMessages.add(message);
```

Introduce new attribute to file `/mystorefront/web/webroot/WEB-INF/tags/desktop/common/globalMessages.tag` like this:

```
<div class="alert neutral ${msg.cssClass}">
    <spring:theme code="${msg.code}" arguments="${msg.attributes}"/>
</div>
```

Keep in mind to check the type of msg before accessing cssClass attribute. Or you replace every GlobalMessage with StylableGlobalMessage. Then you can omit the check.

Comment: Here is a possibility to check the type: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348378/how-to-implement-instanceof-in-jstl Actually not the best practice approach. But since there is a very bad support for extensibility in the acceleratorstorefrontcommons extension, I would think this is the best way.

Comment: You could also use "ant customize" to replace the respective classes with your own implementation.